# How to insert string after every fifth occurrence of another string?

Tags: php, replace

I want to insert string in certain position of character using PHP, so I have string like this:

```
$string = "
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
    <p>15</p>
    <p>16</p>
    <p>17</p>
    ";
```

I want to append this bb code `[next]` after every multiple of 5 `</p>` tag, so it would be like this:

```
$string = "
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    [next] //appended bb code
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
    [next] //appended bb code
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
    <p>15</p>
    [next] //appended bb code
    <p>16</p>
    <p>17</p>
    ";
```

I have a case that I have a post article that needs to paginate after the fifth `</p>`, tenth `</p>`, fifteenth `</p>` and so on. What I have tried is to find and get the number of position of each `</p>` and append the `[next]` bb code when at the tenth paragraph (`</p>`). and that works well.

```
$string = "
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
    <p>8</p>
    <p>9</p>
    <p>10</p>
    <p>11</p>
    <p>12</p>
    <p>13</p>
    <p>14</p>
    <p>15</p>
    <p>16</p>
    <p>17</p>
";
    $paginate = '[next]';
    $found = 0;
    
    for($i = 1; $i <= 99; $i++) {
        $paragraph = strpos($string, "</p>", $found);
        $found = $paragraph + 1;

        if ($i == 10) {
            $string = substr_replace($string, $paginate, $paragraph, 0);
        }
    }

    echo $string;
```

The Result (Output):

```
1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10[next]

11

12

13

14

15

16

17
```

I'm struggling when I'm tried to append that bb code every multiple of 5 `</p>` tag, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some judisious use of `explode()` and `implode()` and th modulus `%` operator, you can do it this way

```
$string = 
"<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
<p>16</p>
<p>17</p>
";
$paginate = '[next]';

$lines = explode("\n", $string);

foreach ($lines as $i => $line) {  
    if ($i != 0 && $i % 5 == 0) {
        $new[] = $paginate;
    }
    $new[] = $line;
}

$string = implode("\n", $new);
echo $string;
```

RESULT

```
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
[next]
<p>6</p>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
<p>10</p>
[next]
<p>11</p>
<p>12</p>
<p>13</p>
<p>14</p>
<p>15</p>
[next]
<p>16</p>
<p>17</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Match every everything up to the fifth `</p>` tag, then forget it all with `\K`, then inject your bbcode.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/bUPvR))

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:.*?</p>){5}\K~s', "\n    [next]", $string);
```

If you want a tag-ignorant pattern, here is one:

```
~((^|\R).+){5}\K~
```

Or fully respecting your system's newline sequences:

```
echo preg_replace('~(?:.+\K\R){5}~', "$0    [next]$0", $string);
```